# Adding a Tileset from mapbox into my map

Tags: html, web-applications, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm new working with mapbox, and recently I want to create a web map. I uploaded a shape into mapbox tilseset cloud, but when I try to add it into a map it doesn't display. This is the code funtion that I'm using:

```
        map.on('load', function() {
        map.addLayer({
            'id' : 'Resguardos',
            'type' : 'fill',
            "source" : {
                'type' : 'vector',
                'url' : 'mapbox://fabiofz1990.9lhgml6c',
            },
            'layout' : {},
            'paint' : {
                'fill-color' : '#0044b2',
                'fill-opacity' : 1
            }
        });

    });
```

Thank you

Comment: have you added the api key to this

Answer (score 7):

You can add tilesets directly from the Mapbox studio.

1. Copy tileset URL.[image: List item]
2. Add URL like this. url: "mapbox://+tilesetid"

```js
map.addSource('tileset_data', {
    "url": "mapbox://abcqqq123.cklxcyxew1b9421lpb8shxf4x-2ikvs",
    "type": "vector"
});
```

3. Add the source name from above source name "tileset_data" in your layer
   and get source-layer from above picture.

```js
       map.addLayer({
           'id': 'circles',
           'type': 'circle',
           'source': 'tileset_data',
           'source-layer': 'children_obesity',
           'paint': {
               'circle-color': '#7F3121',
               'circle-opacity': 0.75,
               'circle-radius': 5
           }
       });
```

Then you good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think to display it you would need to add the tileset data to the style that your are using.

There is an option for that in your mapbox account at: https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---- Updated 2023 ---- :

Add a raster tile source (mapbox official example)

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/

This is my working example. You will need:

step 1) add tile source

step 2) add tile layer based off  the tile source you just created.

[image]

---- Original 2019 ---- :

you can NOT directly add mapbox TileSet into your browser client.

You have to create a new mapbox style, which use your tileSet.

This is working sample

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/766/new-2019-world-press-freedom-ranking-map-180-countries

https://transparentgov.net/json2tree/datahub.io/international/press-freedom-2019-mapbox-style.html

Comment: Is there no way to do this programmatically? What if you have hundreds of tiles and want your app to choose which to display based on user input?